# is it always possible to make a converging sequence to a limit point?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

X is a topology; p $\notin$ A $\subset$ X;
if p is a limit point of A; that is, every [open subset of X containing p] has non-empty intersection with A,
then does there always exist a sequence of A that converges to p?

this is true if X is a metric space, however i am not sure whether this is true or not in general cases.
if it's false, please give me a counterexample.
if this is true, does the proof require any sort of choice-related axioms other than ZFC's?

one more thing;
f : X $\rightarrow$ Y, where X and Y are topologies; x $\in$ X;

assume that for every [sequence x$_n$ of X that converges to x], f(x$_n$) converges to f(x).
then is f continuous on x?; that is, for every [open subset U $\subset$ Y, containing f(x)] there exists an open subset V $\subset$ X s.t. f(V) $\subset$ U

if X is a metric space, one can prove the above by contradiction, making a sequence that converges to x but its image not converging to f(x).

is this true in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true in a metric space, as a metric space is first countable and we can use countable choice to show it (well within ZFC).

It's not true in general: let $X$ be the reals (or any uncountable set) in the co-countable topology. Any sequence in $X$ that converges to $p$ is equal to $p$ after finitely many terms (eventually constant); many proofs exist for this on this site.

So $0 \in \overline{A}$ where $A= (0,\infty)$ but no sequence in $A$ converges to $0$. Also, the identity map from $X$ to $Y$, the reals in the usual topology, is not continuous but trivially sequentially continuous.

Comment: I may be mistaken as I'm certainly not a topologist, but can't these statements be generalized in terms of nets?

Comment: @GaryMoon sure, there is always a net converging from $A$ to $p$ and continuity is net-convergence preservation. But the OP asked for sequences.

Comment: Certainly the OP asked about sequences and I think your answer addresses that issue quite well. I was just a bit curious for myself and also thought that nets would be worth a mention. Anyways +1 for the answer.